# how to devide a string stored in myadmin database and search a word from that string in any sequence?

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my table i have a column for spot name (place name) in which i have a string
like - City Bank Building.

i have my user interface in which i have one search box in that user can enter any keyword for searching.

now i want to search that keyword from the table column spot name which is a string.

so basically i want to extract a substring from the string which is stored in the database.

for example,

City Bank Building - this is the database string
Bank - my search keyword

any combination of the string which contains "Bank" as a word in the string should be display in the list.

this is my code,

```
switch($search_by){
    case "spotname":
        $sql_where_clause = "sname LIKE ' %" . $search_keyword."%'";
        break;
}
```

anyone know how to do this?

Comment: isn't this a basic select * from table_name where spot_name like "%_the_word_you_search_fo%" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    $query="Bank"; //or whatever you are looking for
    $mysql=mysql_connect();
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT `ColumnName` FROM `TableName` WHERE `ColumnName` LIKE '%$query%'", $mysql);
    mysql_close($mysql);

?>
```

The mysql query would become

```
SELECT `ColumnName` FROM `TableName` WHERE `ColumnName` LIKE '%Bank%'
```

Which will select anything that has `Bank` in it. So it will match all of the following

```
City Bank Building
Bank Building
Building Bank
Bank
BankBank
...and so on
```

Comment: There is a space in your code `$sql_where_clause = "sname LIKE ' %" . $search_keyword."%'";` after `LIKE '` and before `%`. Remove that space. Your code should then look like this: `$sql_where_clause = "sname LIKE '%" . $search_keyword."%'";`

Comment: If your php server has string replace module on, then you can directly do `$sql_where_clause = "sname LIKE '%$search_keyword%'";`

Comment: got the answer.the write answer is $sql_where_clause = "sname LIKE '%" . $search_keyword."%'";

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I told you

Answer (score 1):

Using LIKE in your query will only work when your users enter a single word or exact phrase. A better way to do it is to use a full text index search:

```
CREATE TABLE places (
   id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(200),
   FULLTEXT (name)
);
```

Then your query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM places 
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('SEARCH PHRASE');
```

Read more about full text search here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html